# C# streamreader and streamwriter onto same file

Tags: c#, stream, streamreader, streamwriter

How do I read and write onto the same file?

A sample of my code looks like this:

```
List<string> Data = new List<string>();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\manda\Desktop\Schule\Pos1\HüW2Casino\Spieler1.conf");

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\manda\Desktop\Schule\Pos1\HüW2Casino\Spieler1.conf");

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Data.Add(line);
}

int budget = int.Parse(Data[1].Substring(15, 3));

for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++)
{
    if (Data[i] != "ENDE")
    {
        numb = rnd.Next(0, 7);

        if (Data[i].Substring(0,1) == "0" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "1" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "2" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "3" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "4" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "5" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "6" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "7")
        {
            betnumb = int.Parse(Data[i].Substring(0, 1));
            betamount = int.Parse(Data[i].Split(' ') [1]);

            if (betnumb == numb)
            {
                budget += betamount * 7;
            }
            else
            {
                budget -= betamount;
            }

            if (budget < 0)
            {
                sw.Write("Pleite");
                Console.WriteLine("Pleite");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems like I can't read and write onto the same file, as there are no changes to the file, never.

Maybe anyone knows what my problem is?

Comment: try to add `sw.Flush();` after `sw.Write("Pleite");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Flush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.flush?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Stream_Flush) to reflect the changes to file or set [StreamWriter.AutoFlush = true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
List<string> Data = new List<string>();
string path = @"C:\Users\manda\Desktop\Schule\Pos1\HüW2Casino\Spieler1.conf"

FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

while ((line=sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Data.Add(line);
}

int budget = int.Parse(Data[1].Substring(15, 3));

for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++)
{
    if (Data[i] != "ENDE")
    {
       numb = rnd.Next(0, 7);

       if (Data[i].Substring(0,1) == "0" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "1" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "2" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "3" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "4" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "5" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "6" || Data[i].Substring(0, 1) == "7")
       {
           betnumb = int.Parse(Data[i].Substring(0, 1));
           betamount = int.Parse(Data[i].Split(' ') [1]);

           if (betnumb == numb)
           {
              budget+=betamount*7;
           }
           else
           {
               budget -= betamount;
           }

           if (budget < 0)
           {
               sw.Write("Pleite");
               sw.Flush();

               Console.WriteLine("Pleite");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says: "Proccess can't access File "C:\Users\manda\Desktop\Schule\Pos1\HüW2Casino\Spieler1.conf", because another Process is accessing it" right here in the code:

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);

for Streamwriter

Comment: @Sydroce1, Try creating `FileStream` first and pass it to the reader. Check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You never close the `StreamWriter`. Therefore the new content is never flushed and the file is kept open. Enclose the `StreamWriter` in a `using`-statement which automatically flushes and closes the file at the end or whenever the using block is left (can also be because of a `break`, a `return` or and exception).

If your intention is to append data to the file, you can create the writer with `File.AppendText(Path)`.

Since you read the file before you write to it, there is no point in keeping the reader open while writing. You don't even need to create a `StreamWriter`. just read the whole file into an array with `File.ReadAllLines(Path)`.

```
const string Path = @"C:\Users\manda\Desktop\Schule\Pos1\HüW2Casino\Spieler1.conf";

string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(Path);
int budget = Int32.Parse(data[1].Substring(15, 3));

using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Path)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length && data[i] != "ENDE"; i++) {
        numb = rnd.Next(0, 7);
        char digit = data[i][0]; // Take the 1st char instead of Substring(0,1).
        if ('0' <= digit && digit <= '7') { // Chars can be compared like numbers.
            betnumb = digit - '0'; // You can do math on chars.
            betamount = Int32.Parse(data[i].Split(' ')[1]);

            if (betnumb == numb) {
                budget += betamount * 7;
            } else {
                budget -= betamount;
            }
            if (budget < 0) {
                sw.Write("Pleite");
                Console.WriteLine("Pleite"); // German for "bankrupt".
                break; // Probably you don't want to continue looping when bankrupt.
            }
        }
    }
} // Automatically flushes and closes the file here.
```

There are few optimizations and corrections you can make. I guess that you want to stop the for-loop when `"ENDE"` (German for "end") is reached. You can do this by adding this condition to the for-loop-condition: `i < data.Length && data[i] != "ENDE"`.

Probably you also don't want to continue looping when bankrupt (`budget < 0`). You can exit the loop with `break;`. If you do this, it also means that you only write once the file. In this case you can even simplify the file writing. Instead of using a `StreamWriter`:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Path)) {
    ...
    sw.Write("Pleite");
    ...
}
```

... you can simply write:

```
    File.AppendAllText(Path, "Pleite");
```

With this simplification the code becomes:

```
const string Path = @"C:\Users\manda\Desktop\Schule\Pos1\HüW2Casino\Spieler1.conf";

string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(Path);
int budget = Int32.Parse(data[1].Substring(15, 3));

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length && data[i] != "ENDE"; i++) {
    numb = rnd.Next(0, 7);
    char digit = data[i][0]; // Take the 1st char instead of Substring(0,1).
    if ('0' <= digit && digit <= '7') { // Chars can be compared like numbers.
        betnumb = digit - '0'; // You can do math on chars.
        betamount = Int32.Parse(data[i].Split(' ')[1]);

        if (betnumb == numb) {
            budget += betamount * 7;
        } else {
            budget -= betamount;
        }
        if (budget < 0) {
            File.AppendAllText(Path, "Pleite");
            Console.WriteLine("Pleite");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

These static methods in `File` are very handy, as they read or write and open and close the file in one single statement.

You can simplify the range test for the first digit. Instead of calling `data[i].Substring(0,1)` repeatedly, simply store the first character with `char digit = data[i][0];`. Characters behave like integers. You can compare them (`'0' <= digit && digit <= '7'`) and perform calculation on them. `digit - '0'` gets the value of the digit as `int`.

I stored the file path in a constant, to avoid its repetition.

Local variables and method parameters are usually written in camelCase. Therefore I renamed `Data` as `data`.